# python, openpyxl: load workbook with header in specific row

Tags: python, header, openpyxl

the .xls-files I'm trying to load are all uneven, with one exception: the headers are always inside row number three. Is it possible to load a worksheet from row four and with the headers from row three.

My code so far:

```
for p in Path('.').glob('*.xls'):
    wb = load_workbook(p, data_only=True)
    ws = wb['ExampleSheet']

    df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
    df = df.reset_index()
```

Thanks for your help and have a great weekend!

Comment: It doesn't look like you've tried very much but, yes, that should be possible.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding! Of course I tried a few things, but none of it worked!

Comment: You should include the code that you have tried with more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

maby by deleting it(?)
you can delete rows by:
`ws.delete_rows(0, 3)`